# What's the purpose of the [internet] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I was poking around at recently-modified questions today and noticed the [internet](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet) tag on one of them. (It was [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/15177/8366) about Xbox Live and a connection through T-Mobile ... I proposed an edit to it that's since been accepted.)

It seems to me that [xbox-live](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-live) covers the question just fine, especially considering that there is a [similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/4480/8366) (if not identical one) also tagged with just [xbox-360](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-360) and [xbox-live](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-live).

There are only 7 questions tagged with [internet](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet), and I'm not sure that any of them need something other than a system-specific tag or the existing [online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) tag.

Is there a reason to have a separate [internet](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet) tag? If so, let's add a tag excerpt, and if not, can someone burninate it?

Comment: I can see reasons why we would need an internet tag, however all of those reasons would make the question off-topic on gaming. (i.e. My computer won't connect to the internet)

Comment: @wipqozn "i'm connected to the internet but I can't play any game" (firewall)

Comment: @badp excellent point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]