# Wither [autosave]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Just an hour ago [autosave](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autosave) had half a dozen questions listed under it, but now the tag has been emptied. It's still there for the moment, but empty. I'm just wondering what's up with this, is it being deleted or merged? If so, why empty it first?

Comment: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3800/have-we-not-been-clear-enough-that-meta-tags-are-a-bad-thing

Comment: @yx. Well, if that is the case then a mod should just outright delete it and mark it as a bad tag.

Comment: We can't "outright delete" tags. Or even mark tags.

Comment: Oh, I thought tags were outright deleted.

Answer (score 5):

[autosave](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autosave), and some other ones in the same class like [save-points](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/save-points), aren't entirely useful tags to have.

When it comes to a dependent tag, one has to figure the importance of the categorization and the utility of it. Which is to say... "Is autosave a meaningful enough categorization that it deserves to mark itself apart from other questions?". The answer is, in my opinion, no.

We are divorced from subscription on dependent tags - it is unlikely that anyone will ever subscribe and follow a tag like [autosave](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autosave). So their utility relies on how much use they provide for our audience in terms of categorization, in terms of meaningfulness and necessity. Autosave functions, while present in many games, are not something that is an exceptionally meaningful subdivision of an individual game's questions. Meaningful subdivisions help identify entire classes of questions that may be difficult to otherwise group together. You might phrase it as, "What is the likelihood that people will reference the collection of all questions of this class for a given game?". Autosave is the kind of functionality that people are more likely to search for individual problems, not for a set of concepts. To that end, it doesn't really make for a strong and meaningful subdivision.

The same would go for [save-points](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/save-points). I might say [save-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/save-games) as well, but it's got a large number and it would be better to investigate the tag fully before delving into that question.

Answer (score -1):

I removed it because it's a meta tag and [meta tags are bad](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3800/have-we-not-been-clear-enough-that-meta-tags-are-a-bad-thing).

It's not just this tag that is bad. It's *all* meta tags. We're actually kind of on a mini-crusade to flush them out of the system completely. The mods don't have a tool to delete a tag, but some admins can push a button and erase a tag's existence. They tend not to hang around too often or notice all the questions, however, so we do what we can for tags that don't have too many questions on them yet.

We don't want to clutter up the front page by re-tagging hundreds of questions at once, because some of the meta tags are pretty wide-spread, but we do want to get rid of the simple ones and put some spotlights on the less-than-trivial ones.

Comment: Meta tags describe the question itself -- e.g., `subjective`.  A question tagged that is not likely to be "about subjective".  A question tagged `autosave` is likely to be about autosaves, though.  It's a real tag -- dependent on the game tag it's used with and probably not useful, as Grace says, but not a meta tag.

Comment: Next time just put in an entry in the tag wiki saying it is slated for removal. Documentation along the way helps keep things clear.

Comment: @CyberSkull I don't see how that's necessary. The act of me manually removing that tag from all questions it was on should speak for itself. No need to edit the tag wiki for something that's going to be deleted in short order.

Comment: No, it's not. Just a sentence saying "This tag is going away." helps someone walking into the situation.

Comment: @CyberSkull I maintain that it is unnecessary. An empty tag is empty for one reason and one reason only: it was specifically removed from all the questions that it once existed on. There isn't even any way to access that tag at that point without specifically searching for it. It's a small enough audience of people who might get confused that I'm willing to take that risk.