# How do you "Create" a tag, and should we create one for "Minecraft-crash" questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Every now and again, I see mention of "created a tag for you", or "can someone make a tag for me". and I was wondering how exactly it works out?

For example I have "created" a tag for [samurai-siege](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samurai-siege), for one question once, and didn't think much of it.

However, after some [discussion about all the Minecraft crash questions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10088/vast-amounts-of-minecraft-crash-questions), someone suggested creating a [minecraft-crash](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-crash) tag.

So, what are the requirements to create a tag, and should we make one for this specific type of question?

Comment: I am aware that there is one for the [tag:minecraft-crash-landing] modpack.

Answer (score 2):

The requirement is 300 reputation, and a bit of judgement.

That's it. Occasionally someone asks a question that needs a tag that doesn't exist, but they don't have 300 rep. For example, maybe a new game has been released and the first person to ask a question is a new user. Someone who does have 300 rep will usually fix this for them. Sometimes unprompted, after noting that the wrong tag is on the question, or sometimes, by request after a post on meta or an ask in chat. All of those things are normal and fine.

You have the 300 rep, so use your judgement, and don't make any [Meta Tags.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/on-the-coming-murder-of-dependent-and-meta-tagging)

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for cleaning that up. I meant to link my previous discussion on the minecraft crash topic (edited) so what do you think of using this to clear up some of the questions?

Comment: The linked meta post you suggested does have some merit in my mind for this topic as well, specifically the "too specific tags should be burninated." As you say, it's up to my good judgement, but I do like to keep some structure going :)