# There should be a tag on trouble shooting

Tags: discussion, tags

Fro past experiences I have always seen posts that are on troubleshooting a game. should we add a tag on troubleshooting for this. If we cant can someone tell me why?

Comment: Just FYI, downvotes on meta don't mean people dislike your question - they are used to indicate that people disagree with what you are suggesting. So don't get downhearted - downvotes mean people are engaging with what you're saying :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We do: [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues).

Answer (score 2):

### Nope.

The community has previously decided that [most non-game title tags are a bad thing](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3800/have-we-not-been-clear-enough-that-meta-tags-are-a-bad-thing) because they do not add much value. One does not become an expert in "troubleshooting" all kinds of games, users are experts in troubleshooting the issues related to a specific game, so the specific game tag is much more useful than the generic "troubleshooting" tag.

The "troubleshooting" term itself is no good, as that implies a vague back and forth discovery process that does not really work with our Q&A format. We are not a discussion forum. Tech support type questions here work best when the poster has done a good amount of the troubleshooting already and incorporates that info into the question when they post.

The last point is exactly what you mentioned. We have a lot of questions here that involve troubleshooting some aspect of a game. We have so many that it would not be a good use of volunteer time to try and make sure that all of them are tagged with a new "troubleshooting" tag.

Comment: We have [technical-issues]

Comment: @Robotnik that'll teach me to meta in the middle of the night

Comment: yea I guess but It would be sort of helpful to let people know that they are having a trouble shooting question, sort of like a sub tag.